# Move to the definition for PHP constants in Aptana

Tags: hyperlink, constants, aptana, zend-studio, code-assist

I used to work with Zend Studio where it was possible to go to the definition for constants using hyper-linking "ctrl+click" (as for functions, vars, etc.)

I switched to Aptana studio 3.0 and customized my way well except on this point.
Does anyone knows if it's possible to manage PHP constants in Aptana the same way as with Zend Studio?

This is not fundamental but could be very useful to retrieve a constant (I precise that typing the name of a constant works well with code assist. It's just to get back to the definition by clicking that's seems impossible)

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: I can confirm this. With latest build as of today, constants defined with define() statement outside of a class, but included, cannot be CTRL-clicked. It works in Zend Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried that:

File a.php:

```
<?php
class TestClass {
const TEST_CONST1 = 0;
const TEST_CONST2 = -1;
const TEST_CONST3 = 5;
const TEST_CONST4 = -5;
}
```

File b.php:

```
<?php
TestClass::TEST_CONST1;
```

Clicking Ctrl and hovering over the `TEST_CONST1` shows a link. Clicking that link opens `a.php` on line 3.

1. Use the latest Studio.
2. Make sure that your project was created using the Aptana PHP project creation wizard. The `Nature` of the project that is created this way effects the functionality of the Content Assist and the linking.
3. In case your project was imported, you can still set the Aptana PHP `Nature` by right-clicking the project --> Select `properties` --> Select `Project Natures` --> Select the `PHP` item.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks sgibly  for your help ;)

My project was created at first in Zend Studio and retrieved in Aptana from an SVN repository.
As the ".project" file embedded was created by ZS, I've checked the "PHP nature" in project properties and made it "primary".
I also unckecked ZS specific PHP natures that might collide with Aptana's PHP.

Following your example, he hyper-linking is supported. 
But ZS was able to hyper-link to a constant defined with the PHP define() function outside of a class.
The most frustrating is that constants are available in code assist. But clicking on them has no effect.

Comment: Hmm... I thought I've implemented that :) In any case, you can open a ticket at http://jira.appcelerator.org/secure/CreateIssue!default.jspa with some code samples (a zipped project will do). In case you found my answer above useful, you are welcome to accept it :)

Comment: @sgibly, I can confirm this. With latest build as of today, constants defined with define() statement outside of a class, but included, cannot be CTRL-clicked. It works in Zend Studio.

Comment: @Marcus can you open a ticket? Thanks!

Comment: @sgibly, please take a look at the ticket. It was closed incorrectly and with very little effort. I'm sorely disappointed.

Comment: @MarcusAdams The ticket was re-opened. No worry :)

Answer (score 0):

Select project and set the Aptana PHP Nature by right-clicking the project --> Select properties --> Select Project Natures --> Select the PHP item.